# What happens to Euler's $V+F-E=2$ when $V$, $F$, and $E$ reach infinity?

Tags: graph-theory

Does Euler's formula in any way help us tell when an infinite graph is planar? Precisely because 
 "$\infty +\infty-\infty=2$" makes no sense whatsoever.

Comment: The phrase "reach infinity" makes no sense. Euler's relation is true for a large class of finite structures. If there is a particular place in your reading where you a puzzled by what it says (possibly for large $v$) then [edit] the question to ask about that.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Of course this question in its current form doesn't belong here. However, I think it's worth  noting that there **is** an interesting question here: namely, does Euler's formula in any way help us tell when an *infinite* graph is planar? Precisely because "$\infty+\infty-\infty=2$" makes no sense whatsoever, this is an interesting question, and actually has a very good answer. So I hope the OP will improve their post so that it meets the standards of this site.

Comment: ... OK, I guess copy/pasting from my comment is technically an improvement, but come on: please put some effort into this question. Have you tried anything? Can you think of any infinite graphs whose planarity you're especially interested in? Etc.

Comment: I mean, $V+F=E+2$ makes sense and presumably is still true for infinite planar graphs.

Comment: I'm a non-math person taking a first stab at graph-theory, purely as a hobby. I teach English. Obviously, this is the wrong site for a newbie like me.  Thanks for your time.

Comment: When I asked ChatGPT the question above, it came up with this: "The fact that the variables are infinite doesn't change the meaning of the equation, but it would make solving the equation impossible because infinite numbers cannot be added or subtracted."  ....I hope that is wrong.

Comment: @PGT What you got from ChatGPT is worse than wrong. It's nonsense. As for you other comment - newbies (you in particular) are welcome here. We will help you answer particular well posed questions.

Comment: @PGT the question was not well received initially not because you are newbie, but because the question was poorly written. It's ok to be newbie, but you should include your thoughts about the question, what you understand about it and what you don't understand, why you are interested and similar information. As you can see yourself, we try to engage with people here to help them learn, we don't just blindly answer questions, especially when they are poorly written.

Comment: @Ennar Well, this is not true for all users ...

Answer (score 4):

Here is a theorem which might make the connection you desire.

**Fact:** Let $G$ be a countable graph. If every finite subgraph of $G$ is planar, then $G$ is planar.

Hence if $V - E + F = 2$ for every finite subgraph of an infinite graph, it follows that the infinite graph is planar.

Comment: That is an answer is one that I can understand. I know we are not supposed to thank people, but THANK YOU!!!!

Comment: Where can we find a proof of this "Fact" ?

Comment: @Jean, here's a link to a previous discussion: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1705090/extending-kuratowskis-planarity-theorem-on-finite-graphs-to-countable-infinite

Comment: @Jean, see also Dirac and Schuster, A theorem of Kuratowski, Indag Math 16 (1954) 343-348.

Comment: @Gerry Myerson Thanks !